# MySQL puttin a minimum and maximum limit on GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fill the group_concat with values, no more no less than 4 values, if there is more, create another row of the next 4 until there is no more.

I have this:

| cd_table | GROUP_CONCAT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A04,A01,A00 |
| 2 | A01 |

I need this:

| cd_table | GROUP_CONCAT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A04,A01,A00,false |
| 2 | A01,false,false,false |
| 3 | A04,A01,A00,A03 |
| 3 | A02,false,false,false |

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51b601/3/0

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff

Comment: are you sure 5.1.6 isn't a connector version, not the mysql version?  what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 0):

There are several components to this:

- Limiting the ids to four per row.
- Adding additional rows.
- Adding the `falses`.

This can be incorporated into a query:

```
SELECT cd_guime,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(ds_tbcid), ',false,false,false'), ',', 4)
FROM (SELECT guime.cd_guime, ds_tbcid,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY guime.cd_guime ORDER BY ds_tbcid) as seqnum
      FROM guime JOIN
           gucid
           ON gucid.cd_guime = guime.cd_guime JOIN
           tbcid
           ON gucid.cd_tbcid = tbcid.cd_tbcid
     ) x
GROUP BY cd_guime, CEILING(seqnum / 4.0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=412a94a143d114142f4f5d4531fdbfec) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It really works, but my MySQL is at version 5.1.6 and it doesn't accept this "OVER (PARTITION BY... )". But thanks anyway : )

Comment: @IgorBoldt . . . MySQL 5.1.6 was released in 2008.  It is over a **decade** past the point in time when you should have been upgraded.